# AWS S3 403 Forbidden when uploading photo using fetch

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a form that allow user to send a file, and I want to store it in s3 bucket, everything worked well, but when I moved creating url to backend, and put methor itself on frontent, I all the time get 403 forbidden and cors error, using insomnia i get SignatureDoesNotMatch. There is my function to upload file

```
import { api } from './api';

export const getAwsUrl = async (name: string, base64cv: string) => {
    let binaryFile = base64cv;
    if (binaryFile.includes('base64,')) {
        binaryFile = base64cv.slice(base64cv.indexOf('base64,') + 7);
    }

    const uploadCvOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
        },
        body: Buffer.from(binaryFile, 'base64'),
    };

    let res;
    let shouldFinallyTrigger = true;
    try {
        res = await api.mutation({
            uploadCv: [{ cvInput: { name: name } }, { downloadUrl: true, putUrl: true }],
        });
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            shouldFinallyTrigger = false;
        }
    } finally {
        if (shouldFinallyTrigger) {
            await fetch(res?.uploadCv.putUrl as string, uploadCvOptions);
            return res?.uploadCv.downloadUrl;
        }
    }
};
```

I don't know what can I do now, none of online solutions helps me :(

There are all errors I get from that fetch

```
Access to fetch at 'https://bucket.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Dawid.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=*acckey*&Content-Type=application%2Fjson&Expires=1634547808&Signature=LbRJYi6soZKnqWfx%2BjHxqLvn0%2Bc%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

aws.ts?c737:31 PUT https://bucket.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Dawid.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=*acckey*&Content-Type=application%2Fjson&Expires=1634547808&Signature=LbRJYi6soZKnqWfx%2BjHxqLvn0%2Bc%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read net::ERR_FAILED 403

_callee$ @ aws.ts?c737:31
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:21
getAwsUrl @ aws.ts?c737:3
_callee$ @ VM3000 CareersForm.tsx:101
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:21
pipefyAPiCall @ VM3000 CareersForm.tsx:172
onSubmit @ VM3000 CareersForm.tsx:208
eval @ Form.js?9040:231
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:20709
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js?3069:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:22329
eval @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js?3069:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11309
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:22420
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:5889
Show 12 more frames
aws.ts?c737:31   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at _callee$ (aws.ts?c737:31)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?0fab:25)
```

There is my backend:

```
import { resolverFor } from './zeus'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

export default async (input) => resolverFor("Mutation", "uploadCv", async (args) => {
    const { name } = args.cvInput;
    const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
    });

    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    };

    const putUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', {
        Bucket: params.Bucket,
        Key: `${name}.pdf`,
        ContentType: 'application/pdf',
        Expires: 60 * 60,
        ACL: 'public-read',
    });

    let getUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
        Bucket: params.Bucket,
        Key: `${name}.pdf`,
    });

    let downloadUrl;
    downloadUrl = new URL(getUrl);
    downloadUrl.hostname = `bucket.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com`;
    return { putUrl, downloadUrl: downloadUrl.href };
})(input.arguments)
```

Comment: We need to see the implementation of `api.mutation`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary added

Comment: OK thank you - enable CORS for the bucket with an origin of `*` - that should work\

Comment: didn't work, I needed to remove ACL and expires headers from getSignedUrlPromise